Nesting coordinator layouts
Layout structure
Demo
I'm trying to create a dynamic layout with multiple scrolling view. The following are my intended behavior:

Scroll event from recyclerView1 should expand and collapse the top level appbarLayout.
Scroll events from recyclerView2 should initially expand or collapse the top level appbarLayout and then subsequently expand or collapse the inner most collapsible toolbar.

The main issue I'm facing is:

Only scrolling recyclerView2 works as intended.
When I scroll recyclerView1 first, and then scroll recyclerView2, then top level appbar layout stop reacting to scrolling events from recyclerView2.

Here is my xml file.
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
         <TextView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:text="Outer collapsing toolbar"
             android:textColor="@color/white"
             android:textSize="18sp"
             android:layout_height="100dp"
             android:background="@color/black"/>
     </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
 </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <com.example.myapplication.NestedCoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#131E3A"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:text="Inner collapsing toolbar"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:background="@color/white"/>
                </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
        </com.example.myapplication.NestedCoordinatorLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Here is my implementation of the NesteCoordinatorLayout. What I do in this class is the relay scroll event to outmost coordinatorLayout.
public class NestedCoordinatorLayout extends CoordinatorLayout implements NestedScrollingChild2, NestedScrollingParent2 {
private final NestedScrollingChildHelper nestedScrollingChildHelper;
public NestedCoordinatorLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    nestedScrollingChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
    nestedScrollingChildHelper.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
}


public NestedCoordinatorLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context, attributeSet);
    nestedScrollingChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
    nestedScrollingChildHelper.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
}
@Override
public boolean startNestedScroll(int axes, int type) {
    return nestedScrollingChildHelper.startNestedScroll(axes, type);
}

@Override
public void stopNestedScroll(int type) {
    nestedScrollingChildHelper.stopNestedScroll();
}

@Override
public boolean hasNestedScrollingParent(int type) {
    return nestedScrollingChildHelper.hasNestedScrollingParent();
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchNestedScroll(int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed, @Nullable int[] offsetInWindow, int type) {
    return nestedScrollingChildHelper.dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, offsetInWindow, type);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchNestedPreScroll(int dx, int dy, @Nullable int[] consumed, @Nullable int[] offsetInWindow, int type) {
    return nestedScrollingChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, offsetInWindow, type);
}

@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(View child, View target,  int axes,
                                    int type) {
    boolean unused = nestedScrollingChildHelper.startNestedScroll(axes, type);
    return super.onStartNestedScroll(child, target, axes, type);
}
@Override
public void onStopNestedScroll(View target, int type) {
    nestedScrollingChildHelper.onStopNestedScroll(target);
    super.onStopNestedScroll(target, type);
}

@Override
public void onNestedScroll(View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed,
                           int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed,  int type) {
    dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, null, type);
    super.onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, type);
}

@Override
public void onNestedPreScroll( View target, int dx, int dy,int[] consumed,
                               int type) {
    dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, null, type);
    if(consumed[1] == 0) {
        super.onNestedPreScroll(target, dx, dy, consumed, type);
    }
}

}
